# map function in python throwing error to unpack values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to run the following speed of code

```
punctDict = {'(':' ( ',')':' ) ','\t':'','\n':''}

for keys,value in map(re.escape, punctDict.keys(  )):
    print(keys,value)
```

It works fine and gives me an expected output

But if I try with `punctDict = {'(':' ( ',')':' ) ','t':'','n':''}`

The above for loop throws an exception as

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `for keys,value` to unpack a string with only one character in it. Observe the difference in output between this:

```
>>> punctDict = {'(':' ( ',')':' ) ','\t':'','\n':''}
>>> map(re.escape, punctDict.keys())
['\\)', '\\(', '\\\t', '\\\n']
```

and this:

```
>>> punctDict = {'(':' ( ',')':' ) ','t':'','n':''}
>>> map(re.escape, punctDict.keys())
['\\)', '\\(', 't', 'n']
```

Notice that in the second example, 't' and 'n' just become 't' and 'n', and single-character strings cannot be unpacked using the comma notation. Since you're only `re.escape()`-ing the keys of your `punctDict`, you should not expect to get both keys and values in your for loop.

The `keys,value` that you are running here isn't actually accessing the keys and values of `punctDict` both `re.escape()`-d, but rather only escaping the keys and trying to split the string (and succeeding because the string has only 2 characters.

You can see the same behaviour if you compare this:

```
>>> firstPart, secondPart = 'xy'
>>> firstPart
'x'
>>> secondPart
'y'
```

with this:

```
>>> firstPart, secondPart = 'x'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 1, in <module>
    firstPart, secondPart = 'x'
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

and even this:

```
>>> firstPart, secondPart = 'xyz'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1, in <module>
    firstPart, secondPart = 'xyz'
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 1):

[map() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) outputs an iterator, which cannot unpack to a key and value tuple.

For going around that you can use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to map your dictionary keys to escape it.

Here's a sample:

---

```
import re

punctDict = {
    '(': ' ( ',
    ')':' ) ',
    '\t':'',
    '\n':''
}

escaped_punct_dict = { re.escape(key) : value for (key,value) in punctDict.items() }

for keys, value in escaped_punct_dict.items():
    print(keys,value)
```

Comment: _map() function outputs an iterator, which cannot unpack to a key and value tuple._ - In general yes, but OP's first input is one example of a situation in which unpacking does work on the values in an iterator. It depends on what the iterator is outputting :)